# In Windows, how can I find out if a GPU is detachable?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx

In Windows, how can I find out if a GPU is detachable?

If I run dxdiag.exe and save a report, it gives me the value:

`Detachable GPU: Yes`

How can I get this value programmatically? I want to avoid calling dxdiag.exe and dumping the result to a file and parsing it since it is quite slow, and I only need one value.

Comment: WMI has this information.

Comment: I tried WMI first but couldn't find it, any idea exactly what to look for?

Comment: Try the WMI `Win32_VideoController` class